# Retrieve end user information from IdP in a sequence

Tags: wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

There is a legacy Rest service which has its own authentication architecture (self-owned db to store user information and using basic auth). Other rest services are all using `Keycloak` as IdP (with OpenID as token).

I'm trying to use WSO2 API manager before the legacy Rest API that it can authenticate calls using OpenID just as other api services. I found there's a guide saying [how to pass the end user attributes to the back-end service](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/) and also how to pass [a custom authorization token to the back-end service](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/).

And now, I want to know whether it is possible to retrieve the caller's id (viz., the end user id) in a sequence or not? It means I can get the end user's id from a property, modify it and then set it to the `Authorization` header.

Thus, the complete process seems as:

1. An end user generates a JWT token from Keycloak
2. The end user calls an api published by API Manager with the token
3. API Manager retrieves the end user's `userid` and sets it into the `Authorization` header
4. API Manager calls the back-end service with the changed `Authorization` header

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your requirement? AFAIU, you want to catch the Backend JWT Token that is generated from API Manager and extract the End User's ID in the `in-sequence` and set it to the Authorization header and send it to the backend. Is my understanding correct? or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: @Athiththan You are correct, and that is what I want to implement. I also add the process in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing the following sequence as an in-sequence to your API. The following sequence retrieves the End User ID using the Synapse Properties and assigns it to the `Authorization` Header.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="username-header">
    <property name="userid" expression="$ctx:api.ut.userName"/>
    <!-- property name="userid" expression="$ctx:api.ut.userId"/ -->
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="User ID" expression="$ctx:userid" />
    </log>

    <property name="Authorization" expression="$ctx:userid" scope="transport" action="set" />
</sequence>
```

Furthermore, you can also try using the following Synapse properties, if the above doesn't fulfil your requirement.

- `api.ut.username`
- `api.ut.userId`

If you are trying to read the end user's ID from the Backend JWT token that is generated by the API Manager during the API invocation, then it is required to come up with an extended mediation sequence, to read and decode the Token, and then to extract the information. Given below is a sample (not complete) if the requirement is as described above

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="admin--AssertionAPI:v1.0.0--In">
    <property name="assertion" expression="$trp:X-JWT-Assertion" />
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="Assertion" expression="$trp:X-JWT-Assertion" />
    </log>
    <property name="Body" expression="base64Decode(fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($ctx:assertion, '.'), '.'))" />
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="body" expression="$ctx:Body" />
    </log>

    <!-- use script mediator to access required properties -->
    <!-- and set the value as a header -->
</sequence>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second solution works for I finally found it is the `preferred_username` field what I want. BTW, from the docs, I cannot find descriptions about properties like `$ctx:api.ut.userName` and `$ctx:api.ut.userId`. Would you mind if let me know what elso I can retrieve from the `api` or `api.ut` properties please?

Comment: You can refer to this [blog](https://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html) for all general properties.